# Linux router - Throughput speed of clients

Tags: linux, debian, networking, internet, router

I have a computer that is configured as a router with two NIC's, one is connected to Internet, the other is connected to the local network switch.

I know that I can get the current throughput of NIC's by creating a script that reads files in the:`/sys/class/net/[dev]/statistics` directory.

But is it possible to get the throughput of every single client on the network, so I can see how much internet bandwidth each client is using?

Comment: It will probably be easier to track that at the perimeter router/firewall level. You can probably set up some reporting per IP address. In the case you can't, you can use a monitoring service to send reports of NIC usage and trend that at a monitoring server (something Nagios would work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have the usage per IP address, You can create an iptable rule for each IP address in the FORWARD chain and track iptables statistics counters.

Taking it from [Network Statistics with iptables and rrdtool](https://fabiobaltieri.com/2012/01/14/network-statistics-with-iptables-and-rrdtool/)

> ```
> iptables -N stats  
> iptables -A stats -s 192.168.0.3 -o $WAN -j RETURN
> iptables -A stats -d 192.168.0.3 -i $WAN -j RETURN  
> iptables -A stats-s 192.168.0.4 -o $WAN -j RETURN 
> iptables -A stats -d 192.168.0.4 -i $WAN -j RETURN 
> iptables -A stats -o $WAN -j RETURN 
> iptables -A stats -i $WAN -j RETURN 
> iptables -A FORWARD -j stats
> ```

In fact I ran in the past an ISP, and they tracked the bandwidth usage of a couple of thousand customers with iptables using this method before I implemented Netflow accounting drinking the data from Cisco routers.

Comment: That was very little dynamical? With this method I have to create a new IPTables rule for every new client that connect to the network.

Comment: As far as I remember in the ISP it was done in perl. Networks do not change so often - you just do it to the whole range, not for every new PC. It worked for them for a few years.

Comment: Yeah, of course. What was I thinking of.